# pandas data frame read_excel: How to look for empty cells?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that is constructed by pd.read_excel.
I want to create a second data frame by selecting all rows of the prior data frame where a column of the excel has a empty cell.

Something like

```
A = df.loc[df["column"]==None]
```

did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `isnull` instead

```
A = df.loc[df["column"].isnull()]
```

Alternatively, you could use `query` because `None` is not equal to itself, this works

```
A = df.query('column != column')
```

Comment: thanks for `column != column`, works for `nan` too. You are an intellectual human beings 

Comment: Holy crap, second one with query is brilliant. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for check `NaN` and `None` values:

```
A = df.loc[df["column"].isnull()]
```

Or if `None` is string:

```
A = df.loc[df["column"]=='None']
```

[Values considered missing in Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing).